# $\{ \sqrt n x^n\}$ is divergent in $(C[0,1],d_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n \in C[0,1]$ such that $f_n(x)=\sqrt nx^n, n \in \Bbb Z^+$. I want to show that $\{f_n\}$ is divergent in $(C[0,1],d_2)$.

I use the definition and got this

$$||f||_2 = \sqrt{\int^1_0 (\sqrt nx^n)^2}$$
Which eventually gave me
$$\sqrt {\cfrac {n} {2n+1}}$$
Taking $n$ to infinity gives me $1$ as the limit. This isn't divergent... what am  I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to show that the sequence of functions is divergent?

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm trying to do. It should be divergent but I somehow got the opposite

Comment: In general, if a sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges, then so is $\{\|f_n\|\}$. However, that the norm $\{ \|f_n\|\}$ converges does not imply that the original sequence is convergent. This is true even in the simplest situation: in $\mathbb R$, the sequence $\{ a_n\} = \{(-1)^n\}$ is divergent, even though the norm $\{|a_n|\}=\{1\}$ is constant.

Comment: What is $d_2$? ${}{}$

Comment: $d_2$ is the standard metric so $d_2(a-b)$ in $\Bbb R^n = \sqrt{\Sigma_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|^2}$

It should be divergent in the example as well but I dont know what went wrong.

Comment: That's not $d_2$ here. In your problem $d_2(f,g) =(\int_0^1(f-g)^2)^{1/2}.$

Comment: Letting $n\to \infty$ does not give $1,$ it gives $1/\sqrt 2.$

Comment: How is $d_2$ a metric on $C[0,1]$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done actually shows that the sequence is not convergent!

The point-wise limit is $0$. It it converges in $d_2$ the it must converge to $0$. But $\|f_n\| $ does not tend to $0$ as you have shown. Hence the sequence is not convergent.

[If $f_n \to f$ w.r.t. $d_2$ then there is  subsequence which converges to $f$ almost everywhere. Hence the only possible limit is the zero function].

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way is to check that
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\| f_{n^2} - f_{n^4} \|_2 = 1 $$
so $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in C.$ Then $|f|\le M$ for some positive  M.

$$\int_0^1(\sqrt nx^n-f(x))^2\,dx = \int_0^1 (nx^{2n} -2\sqrt nx^nf(x)+f(x)^2)\,dx$$ $$\ge \frac{n}{2n+1} - 2M\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1} +\int_0^1f(x)^2\,dx.$$

As $n\to \infty,$ the last expression $\to \dfrac{1}{2} + 0 + \int_0^1f(x)^2\,dx.$ This is $\ge \dfrac{1}{2}$ no matter what $f$ is. Therefore $f_n$ cannot converge to any $f\in C$ in the $d_2$ norm.